# Is a number between the 2 square brackets necessary regarding char variables

Tags: arrays, c, initialization, declaration, string-literals

I just started programming in C and I see on the internet people declaring `char`s like, for example, `char name[]`, without putting any number between the 2 square brackets. I used to code in C++ in high school and we always used to put a number when declaring char. Can someone explain when do we put a number, or if it is even necessary to use one when declaring a `char` variable?

I used to do it like this:

```
char name[20] = "John";
```

but I've seen on the internet people doing it like this:

```
char name[] = "John";
```

Comment: With a number you reserve the number of bytes in your array. Without any mention of a number you're effectively using the same number of bytes as that which appears on the right hand side.

Comment: `char name[] = "John";` will automatically define the array length to be `5` and include a nul terminator essential for a valid C string.

Comment: @WeatherVane char name[20] = "john" will also automatically include null term char

Comment: @0___________ *every* undefined array element will be `0` in that case.

Comment: @WeatherVane it is as a bonus. You cant say which one is null term char and which one is "simple", "trivial" zero

Comment: @0___________ they are the same, no difference.

Answer (score 2):

```
char curse[] = "fie! cometh h're and englut mine own coxcomb thee distemperate fooleth!";
```

In this case, the compiler automatically computes the number of bytes, including the null-terminator. The size of the array is equal to the length of the string, plus the null-byte.

```
char curse[100] = "fie! cometh h're and englut mine own coxcomb thee distemperate fooleth!";
```

Whereas, this defines an array of `100` `char`s, and initializes it with a string of `70` or so bytes. The rest of the bytes are initialized to `0`¹. The size of the array is `100` bytes, whereas the length of the string can be determined with `strlen`. NB that the size of the array and the length of the string it contains are not the same.

Aside: It's better to define the array size as a macro instead of having magic numbers all over your code. It's easier to maintain that way.

[1] From C11:

> If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there
> are elements or members of an aggregate, or fewer characters in a
> string literal used to initialize an array of known size than there
> are elements in the array, the remainder of the aggregate shall be
> initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage
> duration.

i.e. `0`.

Answer (score 1):

`char name[] = "John";` will define a char array long enough to accommodate `"John"` (5 chars).

`char name1[20] = "John";` defined an array of 20 `char` and initialization string only takes 5 bytes (abstracting from the rest of bytes) So you can use those remaining 15 bytes for example by appending another string to it.

```
strcat(name1, " Travolta");
`
```

Comment: In the second example the initialisation takes all 20 bytes, not 5. None of them are uninitialised. Unless explicitly defined, bytes are set to `0`.

Comment: @WeatherVane it is the least important part.

Comment: It is quite important. It makes things like `char foo[200] = {0};` possible.

Answer (score 1):

From the C Standard (6.7.9 Initialization)

> 22 **If an array of unknown size is initialized, its size is determined
> by the largest indexed element with an explicit initializer**. The array
> type is completed at the end of its initializer list.

and

> **14 An array of character type may be initialized by a character string
> literal or UTF−8 string literal, optionally enclosed in braces.
> Successive bytes of the string literal (including the terminating null
> character if there is room or if the array is of unknown size)
> initialize the elements of the array.**

So in this declaration of a character array

```
char name[] = "John";
```

that is according to the second quote from the C Standard equivalent to

```
char name[] = { "John" );
```

the array `name` is initialized by the string literal `"John"`.

According to the first quote from the C Standard the size of the array is determined by the number of characters (including the terminating zero character `'\0'`) in the string literal. In fact the above declaration has the same effect as the following declaration

```
char name[] = { 'J', 'o', 'h', 'n', '\0' };
```

So as the number of characters in the string literal is equal to `5` then the array has exactly `5` elements and its size is also equal to `5` because `sizeof( char )` is always equal to `1`.

In this declaration

```
char name[20] = "John";
```

that again may be written like

```
char name[20] = { "John" };
```

the array is declared specifying explicitly `20` elements. The first `5` elements of the array have corresponding explicit initializers (characters of the string literal). All other elements of the array are implicitly initialized by `0`.

Pay attention to that in C you may write

```
char name[4] = "John";
```

that is you may exclude the terminating zero character `'\0'` of the string literal from the list of initializers of the array. In this case the array `name` will not contain a string. In C++ such an initialization is incorrect and the C++ compiler will issue an error for such a declaration.

To output a character array that contains a string you can write for example

```
printf( "name = %s\n", name );
```

For the last shown declaration where the declared array does not contain a string you can write

```
printf( "name = %.*s\n", ( int )sizeof( name ), name );
```

Answer (score 1):

If an array is declared without a size but with an initializer, then the size of the array is taken from the number of elements in the initializer:

```
int foo[] = {0, 1, 2, 3};
```

In this case, `foo` will be 4 elements wide.

```
char bar[] = "fred"; 
char bar[] = { 'f', 'r', 'e', 'd', 0 };
```

In this case, `bar` will be 5 elements wide - the initializers `"fred"` and `{ 'f', 'r', 'e', 'd', 0 }` are equivalent to each other.

If you declare an array with a size *and* an initializer, then the size will be taken from the size expression.  If there are fewer elements in the initializer than the size, then remaining elements will be initialized to 0:

```
int foo[10] = {1, 2, 3}; // elements 3 through 9 will be initialized to 0
```

If there are more elements in the initializer than the array is sized for, then that's a *constraint violation* and the compiler will yell at you:

```
int foo[3] = {1, 2, 3, 4}; // constraint violation, too many elements
                           // in the initializer
```

If you use designated initializers, then the size will either be taken from the number of initializers or the largest designated initializer:

```
int foo[] = {[0] = 1, [9] = 2};
```

`foo` will be 10 elements wide, element 0 will be initialized to 1, element 9 will be initialized to 2, and the remaining elements will be initialized to 0.

If an array is declared without a size *and* without an initializer, then the array type is *incomplete*, and you can't create an instance of an incomplete type.

Note that array sizes are fixed for the lifetime of the array.  C has something called a *variable-length array* where the size of the array is determined by a runtime variable:

```
size_t x = some_size();
int arr[x];
```

However, "variable" in this context only means that the size of the array isn't fixed from definition to definition, not that the array can be resized after it is defined.

In the context of a *function parameter declaration*, `T a[N]` and `T a[]` are "adjusted" to `T *a` - you cannot pass arrays as function parameters, because array expressions "decay" to pointer expressions under most circumstances and what the function actually receives is a pointer.